# Selecting first N rows for each group

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Assume I have a table like this:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | file_name | file_type |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | file1     | 1         |
|  2 | file2     | 1         |
|  3 | file3     | 1         |
|  4 | file4     | 2         |
|  5 | file5     | 2         |
|  6 | file6     | 2         |
|  7 | file7     | 3         |
|  8 | file8     | 3         |
|  9 | file9     | 3         |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm trying to get 2 rows for each `file_type`, so I'm following this hints:

- https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/08/mysql-generating-row-number-for-each-row-using-variable/
- http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group

I'm trying the following query:

```
SELECT file_name, file_type,
  @type_number := IF(@current_type = file_type, @type_number + 1, 1) AS type_number,
  @current_type := file_type
FROM test
ORDER BY file_type
```

But I'm getting the following results:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------+
| file_name | file_type | type_number | @current_type := file_type |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------+
| file1     | 1         |           1 | 1                          |
| file2     | 1         |           1 | 1                          |
| file3     | 1         |           1 | 1                          |
| file4     | 2         |           1 | 2                          |
| file5     | 2         |           1 | 2                          |
| file6     | 2         |           1 | 2                          |
| file7     | 3         |           1 | 3                          |
| file8     | 3         |           1 | 3                          |
| file9     | 3         |           1 | 3                          |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

As you can see the `type_number column` should have values from 1 to 3, but it is `1` on every rows.

Where I am wrong?

Comment: [_Groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit more complicated, you must assign each variable `@type_number` and `@file_type` again.

```
SELECT file_type, file_name, id
FROM (
      SELECT  @type_number := IF(@file_type = file_type, @type_number + 1, 1) AS type_number, 
              @file_type := file_type as file_type, 
              file_name, id
      FROM 
          (SELECT @type_number := 1) x, 
          (SELECT id, file_name, @file_type := file_type as file_type FROM ttest ORDER BY file_type) y
    ) z
WHERE type_number <= 2;
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/IUPWT52140

Comment: I'm trying with the following query (you missed a comma), but I'm getting an error:
`SELECT file_type, file_name
FROM (
    SELECT
        @type_number := IF(@file_type = file_type, @type_number + 1, 1) AS type_number,
        @file_type := file_type as file_type,
        file_name
    FROM 
        (@type_number := 1) x,
        (SELECT file_name, @file_type := file_type as file_type 
         FROM test ORDER BY file_type) y
    ) z
WHERE type_number <= 2;` Error: `[...] near '@type_number := 1) x,
        (SELECT file_name, @file_type := file_type as file' at line 8`

Comment: McNets, could you help me please?

Comment: Missing SELECT in `(SELECT @type_number := 1) x,`